# Remove blocks from Category view

Tags: category, layout, blocks

I'd like to remove the Recent Posts and Newsletter block in the left column of category views - example of the current page at http://objectandline.co.uk/webstore/personal/sketch-note-books.html.

What's the most expedient way? Thanks, Barry

Answer (score 1):

got to your themefolder/layout/catalog.xml . in below `category tag` for `no anchor category` add `remove` in your `left tag`

```
 <catalog_category_default translate="label">
   <reference name="left">
    <remove name="yourblockname"></remove>
  </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

and same goes for anchor category

```
 <catalog_category_layered translate="label">
       <reference name="left">
        <remove name="yourblockname"></remove>
      </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
```

hope this will help..

Answer (score 0):

create local.xml in your magento theme like the path 
app\design\frontend\myPakage\myTheme\layout\local.xml and add the code you created in local.xml

Remove syntax like code.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <layout version="0.1.0">
 <catalog_category_default translate="label">
    <reference name="left">
       <remove name="your newsletter name"></remove>
    </reference>
 </catalog_category_default>
 </layout>
```